# Redirection is not working in my Spring Boot application after deploying in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We implemented OAuth2.0 security in our project, which is working as expected locally with Google App Engine.

In our application we are redirecting to another URL:

```
res.sendRedirect("/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=Alexa&redirect_uri=/authCode");
```

As mentioned, this is working as expected locally. However, when we deployed the same code in Google Cloud Platform, we observed redirection to another URL and it's not working using sendRedirect() in Spring Boot.

Please suggest a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The client_id should be an Oauth client id. As explained in [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/accessing-the-api#authentication_example), App Engine generates `[MY_CLIENT_ID].apps.googleusercontent.com` as Oauth client id.

If your application use languages and frameworks like `PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, and .NET`, you also have to include the endpoints in the Authorized redirect URIs on purpose that the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses.

Check [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred) for more details to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization to access Google APIs.